# Conditional independence and conditional expectation for joint Gaussian vectors.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am reading Hajek's book "Random Processes for Engineers". In example 4.5 it says: Let $X,Y,Z$ be joint Gaussian vectors. Then $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent to each other given $Y$ if and only if 
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y,Z] = \mathbb{E}[X|Y].$$ 
As it said, both $X|Y=y,Z=z$ and $X|Y=y$ are Gaussian. So, their distribution equal to each other if and only if their mean and covariances are the same for every $y$ and $z$. Based on this I can show that conditional independence imply the relation of conditional expectations. But how to show the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $Z$ to get $ZE[X|Y,Z]=ZE[X|Y]$. On the left side you call pull $Z$ inside the conditional expectation so $E[ZX|Y,Z]=ZE[X|Y]$. Now take conditional expectation given $Y$ on both sides. You get $E[XZ|Y]=E[ZE[X|Y]|Y]$. On the right side pull out $E[X|Y]$ to get $E[XZ|Y]=E[X|Y]E[Z|Y]$. Hence covariance of $E[X|Y]$ and $E[Z|Y]$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks Kavi. So the idea is to show that $X|Y$ and $Z|Y$ are uncorrelated because they are joint Gaussian. Nice. There is still one step I couldn't go through: 
$$ E[E[XZ|Y,Z]|Y] = E[XZ|Y] ? $$